# How to use Rsvg in C#/Mono and Cairo

Tags: c#, svg, mono, cairo

In this tutorial, there's an example wich loads a svg file and renders it:
http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cairo/cookbook/#opening-images-including-svg

However, It doesn't compile - it gives an "The name 'Rsvg' does not exist in the current context" error on both my windows and ubuntu setup.

How to solve this?

Comment: How about **yum install librsvg2 librsvg2-devel** (at least for ubuntu)

Comment: That might be part of the solution, but it doesn't give me access to the Rsvg namespace right away...